# Husqvarna 235 Chainsaw Not Start

Tags: chainsaw

Husqvarna 235 chainsaw. Started easily, but would die before could use. Squirted one second blast of carburetor cleaner into spark plug hole. Now not start. There is spark. New plug, air and gas filters.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Does it still pull as easily, after you squirted the carb cleaner into the cylinder?  I've gotten hydraulic lock after doing that.

Comment: That aside, on a 'start and die' problem, I check the spark suppressor screen in the exhaust port.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This really isn't a Home Improvement question (although I know a guy who built his house with a chainsaw). Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.